# Overlapping of shortcuts in macOS for VS Code and Evernote

Tags: shortcut, visual-studio-code, evernote

<kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> is a shortcut that I use widely in VS Code and Evernote for search.

Behaviour in VS Code:
[image]

Behaviour in Evernote:

[image]

**The Problem**.

If both apps are opened, when I press <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> in VS Code, it switches to Evernote automatically and opens its search window:

[image]
.

But that's not happening if Evernote is closed, in that case, it opens the search tab in VS Code, as expected.

How can I get rid of this behaviour?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Open the Evernote preferences and check in the Keyword Shortcuts tab whether "Search in Evernote" is set. If that's the case, this is what is most probably causing this behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, That is issue. In evernote shortcuts Under global "Search in Evernote" was set to Command + Shift + F. After setting to default it worked perfectly.

Comment: I'm glad it works. I've added an answer and would appreciate it if you could mark it as solved to help others with a similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evernote can be configured to set global keyboard shortcuts (from [Customize keyboard shortcuts](https://help.evernote.com/hc/en-us/articles/1500002999041-Customize-keyboard-shortcuts)):

> Global keyboard shortcuts allow you to trigger certain Evernote functions by using a unique key combination on your keyboard, even when Evernote is in the background.

Check whether "Search in Evernote" is set. If that's the case:

- either unset it to prevent the conflict,
- or set it to a different value, like <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>.